# Is that possible to develop windows 8 apps on windows 8.1 OS

Tags: windows, windows-8, project, windows-8.1

My OS is Windows 8.1, I want to develop Windows 8 apps, not 8.1. Is it possible? If yes, how can I create Windows 8 project on Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use Visual Studio 2012.